# `post_via_redirect` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm going through the Rails Tutorial Book and by Chapter 8, when running bin/rails test I got this message:

```
 DEPRECATION WARNING: `post_via_redirect` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Please use follow_redirect! manually after the request call for the same behavior.
```

The code generating this message is on `test/integration/user_signup_test.rb`:

```
      test "valid signup information" do
        get signup_path
        assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
          post_via_redirect users_path, user: { name:  "Example User",
                                        email: "user@example.com",
                                        password:              "password",
                                        password_confirmation: "password" }
        end
        assert_template 'users/show'
      end
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Fixed Code**

```
test "valid signup information" do
  get signup_path
  assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
    post users_path, params: { user: { name:  "Example User",
                                        email: "user@example.com",
                                        password:              "password",
                                        password_confirmation: "password" } } 
    follow_redirect!
  end
  assert_template 'users/show'
end
```

**NOTE:** I also added the `params` hash as suggested by Rails 5.